# Nested Loop - more than 4 for loops in one single program

Tags: matlab

I have a text file loaded in matlab. this text file has two columns and 22800 rows. I have written a few calculations using nested for loops. I want all these calculations to be done for every 50 values in the text file. i.e. i want the outer most loop to work for 22800/50 times, which i am unable to code. kindly help me.
my program is as follows.

```
load('assignment_1.txt');
a=-
b=-
m=1;
n=100;
for R=m:n
    if ----
        ---
    else
        ---
    end
    for ---
        if ---
            ----
        end
        for ----
            if----
                -----
            else
                ----
            end

            m=m+100;

            n=n+100;

        end

        y=polyfit(----);

        f=polyval(---);

        plot(-----);

        axis([- - - - ])
    end
end
```

Comment: As a general rule, you should try and avoid writing MATLAB code that contains nested loops like this.  Most of MATLAB's functions will work on vectors or matrices without having to write a `for`loop.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to loop from 1 to 22800 skipping every 50 numbers, you can use the following syntax:

```
for R = 1:50:22800

end
```

Inside of the loop R will have the value `1,51,101,151,...,22751`. If you would rather have `50,100,150,...,22800`, then use the syntax `R = 50:50:22800`. See [this](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/colon.html) for more information about this colon syntax.